# Manipulating the values of each file in a folder using a dictionary and loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

How do I go about manipulating each file of a folder based on values pulled from a dictionary? Basically, say I have x files in a folder. I use pandas to reformat the dataframe, add a column which includes the date of the report, and save the new file under the same name and the date.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pathlib2 as Path
import os

source = Path("Users/Yay/AlotofFiles/April")

items = os.listdir(source)

d_dates = {'0401' : '04/1/2019', '0402 : 4/2/2019', '0403 : 04/03/2019'}

for item in items:
   for key, value in d_dates.items():

        df = pd.read_excel(item, header=None)
        df.set_columns = ['A', 'B','C']
        df[df['A'].str.contains("Awesome")]
        df['Date'] = value
        file_basic = "retrofile"
        short_date = key 
        xlsx = ".xlsx"
        file_name = file_basic + short_date + xlsx
        df.to_excel(file_name)
```

I want each file to be unique and categorized by the date. In this case, I would want to have three files, for example "retrofile0401.xlsx" that has a column that contains "04/01/2019" and only has data relevant to the original file. 
The actual result is pretty much looping each individual item, creating three different files with those values, moves on to the next file, repeats and replace the first iteration and until I only am left with three files that are copies of the last file. The only thing that is different is that each file has a different date and are named differently. This is what I want but it's duplicating the data from the last file. 
If I remove the second loop, it works the way I want it but there's no way of categorizing it based on the value I made in the dictionary.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're trying to do and where the problem is (which I think is why there aren't any answers yet).  Can you provide an example of the desired inputs matched to the desired outputs?  Like a list of the input filenames and a list of the output filenames which correspond to them?

Comment: Yeah of course. The file path "Users/Yay/AlotofFiles/April" contains three excel files. I want go ahead and reformat those files because the way the data is presented is weird, and I'm only interested in certain rows that contain "Awesome". Basically I'm filtering the data and creating that on a new excel file. Each file has unique values for each row that contains "Awesome". I want to perform the same process of reformatting for each file. I have created a loop that goes into the Users/Yay/AlotofFiles/April folder and does what I want to do. It generates three new files that reformats it ...

Comment: ...the way I want. Now each file has data for a given day, I want to be able to categorize them. If i have three files, "retrofile0401_raw.xlsx, retrofile0402_raw.xlsx, retrofile0403_raw.xlsx, I would want those files reformatted and then labeled "retrofile0401.xlsx, retrofile0402xlsx, retrofile0403.xlsx. If I were to open retrofile0401.xlsx, I should see the values for column 'A', 'B', 'C' and a new column for 'Date" which in this case be 04/01/2019 which wasn't there before under "retrofile0401_raw.xlsx.

Comment: By implementing the second loop, it performs this part but at the expense of simply making three copies of the last file retrofile0403_raw.xlsx. Because I am assuming logically, it the loop goes through the first file, makes three copies of the first file each with each file out of the three extracting values from the loop, and then proceeds to the second file, performs the same thing and overwrites the first iteration and then repeats until there's there's only three copies of the last file.

Comment: Still confused, sorry.  You have three files coming in.  Do you want to write three new files or nine new files or some other number?

Comment: I want to create three new files based on the original files. I want to add a date value and rename the new file from values from the dictionary. The issue is that this code is just making three copies of the last file instead of each file.

Comment: Note that your current code can't work: `d_ dates` should be `d_dates`.  Can you double-check that the rest of the code matches what you're actually using?

Comment: Thank you for that. It should be good now.

Comment: If retrofile0401_raw.xlsx has three rows of "Awesome" and values 1,2,3. If retrofile0402_raw.xlsx has three rows of "Awesome" and values 4,5,6. If retrofile0403_raw.xlsx has three rows of "Awesome" and values 7,8,9. I want to have new files generated retrofile0401.xlsx, retrofile0402xlsx, retrofile0403.xlsx with their respective data and new columns with each new date. Instead my code results in retrofile0401.xlsx with values 7,8,9 with "Date" 04/01/2019, retrofile0402xlsx with values 7,8,9 with "Date" 04/02/2019, and retrofile0403.xlsx with values 7,8,9 and "Date" 04/04/2019

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  I'm only making input filenames explicit to make clear what's going on.  You can continue to use yours from the source.

```
input_filenames = [
    'retrofile0401_raw.xlsx', 
    'retrofile0402_raw.xlsx', 
    'retrofile0403_raw.xlsx',]

date_dict = {
    '0401': '04/1/2019', 
    '0402': '4/2/2019', 
    '0403': '04/03/2019'}

for filename in input_filenames:
    date_key = filename[9:13]
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)
    df[df['A'].str.contains("Awesome")]
    df['Date'] = date_dict[date_key]
    df.to_excel('retrofile{date_key}.xlsx'.format(date_key=date_key))
```

`filename[9:13]` takes characters #9-12 from the filename.  Those are the ones that correspond to your date codes.

Comment: Can you please explain the.. date_key = filename[9:13] ?

Comment: Updated answer.